# Is there an iteractive firewall extension available for Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall

Every time something on my computer tries to contact an external host or an external host tries to contact my computer I would like to be asked if I authorize this and if I would like to create a rule to silently allow or  block all the connections like that (and choose/customize the attributes that will be used to identify them) in future.

I don't mind if the rule can't be application-specific, protocol/port/host specificity is enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help you? If not and you have the time, I could learn something from an explanation of why not.

I installed Gufw Firewall from http://gufw.org

From their Help Page:
The available options for rules are Allow, Deny, Reject, and Limit:

```
Allow: The system will allow entry traffic for a port.
Deny: The system will deny entry traffic to a port.
Reject: The system will deny entry traffic to a port and will inform the requesting for connection system that it has been rejected.
Limit: The system will deny connections if an IP address has attempted to initiate 6 or more connections in the last 30 seconds.
```